# Does my function return nothing or do I assign it wrong to the variable?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I try to get an array of objects back from a database request like this (I know I should do this with promise or callback but for the meantime I want to do it with this timeout workaround):

```
var theArray = sql.getArray(id);

setTimeout(function() {
   console.log(theArray);
}, 5000);

getArray: function(ID) {
   var array = [];
   db.each(`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = ?`, ID, (err, row) => {
      array.push(row)
   });

   setTimeout(function() {
      return array;
   }, 1000);
}
```

In the `getArray` function near the return part, the array contains data but in the logging function I get `undefined`.

Why does it contain nothing?

I've read for days now about callbacks and promises but I still dont get it. If someone could provide an example it would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't return anything from the `getArray` function. Therefore, it returns `undefined`.

**Update:**

You need to use promises to get the value back. See the sample below:

```
getArray: function(ID) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        db.all(`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = ?`, ID, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            return resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm new to javascript. I have `return array;` in `getArray ` function. What is the right way to return the array?